# Appending a unique id to simple_form generated radio button inputs and a matching value to the associated label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, radio-button, simple-form

I have the following object:

```
# Table name: interests
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  client_id  :integer
#  condition  :string(255)
belongs_to :client
```

I use the following form to create new objects:

```
= simple_form_for interest do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
    = f.hidden_field :client_id, value: interest.client_id
    = f.input :condition, as: :radio_buttons, collection: ['Used', 'New'], boolean_style: :inline

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

I render this form multiple times on the same page and am having an issue with the IDs of each radio button input matching an ID of the same input in every form on the page.

This is what is rendered multiple times on the page:

```
<div class="input radio_buttons optional interest_condition">
  <label class="radio_buttons optional control-label">Condition</label>
  <span class="radio">
    <input class="radio_buttons optional" id="interest_condition_used" name="interest[condition]" type="radio" value="Used">
      <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="interest_condition_used">Used</label>
    </input>
  </span>
  <span class="radio">
    <input class="radio_buttons optional" id="interest_condition_new" name="interest[condition]" type="radio" value="New">
      <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="interest_condition_new">New</label>
    </input>
  </span>
</div>
```

**My attempted solution:**

Every form has access to a unique id through `interest.client_id`.  I intend on changing the `id` on the `input` and the `for` on the following `label` to something using that id to ensure every version is unique:

```
= f.input :condition, as: :radio_buttons, collection: ['Used', 'New'], 
    boolean_style: :inline, 
    input_html: { id: 'interest_condition' + interest.client_id.to_s}, 
    label_html: {for: 'interest_condition' + interest.client_id.to_s}
```

But this does two things wrong:

- I lose the dynamic id that is typically generated by the collection, each `id`/`for` is literally `interest_condition#{interest.client_id}` rather than `interest_condition_new#{interest.client_id}` and `interest_condition_used#{interest.client_id}`.
- And assigning the `label_html` `for` value with `label_html: {for: 'interest_condition' + interest.client_id.to_s}` assigns the `for` value for the parent label for the collection of radio buttons rather than the label that comes after the radio button itself (this is enabled with `boolean_style: :inline`)

Example of code generated by above code:

```
<div class="input radio_buttons optional interest_condition">
  <label class="radio_buttons optional control-label" for="interest_condition7">
    Condition
  </label>
  <span class="radio">
    <input class="radio_buttons optional" id="interest_condition7" name="interest[condition]" type="radio" value="Used">
    <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="interest_condition_used">
      Used
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="radio">
    <input class="radio_buttons optional" id="interest_condition7" name="interest[condition]" type="radio" value="New">
    <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="interest_condition_new">
      New
    </label>
  </span>
</div>
```

How would I append a value custom to each specific form rendered on the page to the `id` and `form` attributes of my radio buttons?

Answer (score 1):

I have come across a case where I needed unique IDs for each radio option in a collection of radio buttons.

Rather than creating a custom input and overriding Simple Form's CollectionRadioButtonInput or creating a custom wrapper using the Wrapper API, I used the `namespace` option.

```
= f.input_field :my_field, as: :radio_buttons, namespace: "unique_prefix_to_be_prepended_to_id", boolean_style: :inline
```

The namespace will be prepended to the automatically generated ID that SimpleForm generates based on your models and fields names. For example, let's say I have the following form for a User.

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
   = f.input_field :my_field, as: :radio_buttons, namespace: "unique"
```

The HTML `<input>` tag for the 'Yes' radio button option will automatically have an id of `unique_user_my_field_true`. The 'No' radio button option will have an id of `unique_user_my_field_false`. Of course, this is assuming you are only using a yes/no T/F scenario for radio buttons.

Comment: Hi, I like this namespace option. Is it part of simple_form options? Can't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for an association here.  Try this:

```
f.association :client, label_method: :condition
```

and see if that appends `_#{id}` to each of your `input#id`s

provided you can do this:

```
Interest.first.client.condition
```

and get the expected value, I think the above should work

Answer (score 0):

As (what I hope is) a temporary fix, I let the page load then I update all of the `input` `id` attributes and `label` `for` attributes using coffeescript:

```
$ ->
  $('.ids-updated-by-js').each (index) ->
    $(this).find('span').each ->
      span = $(this)
      id = span.find('input').attr('id')
      span.find('input').attr('id', id + index)
      span.find('label').attr('for', id + index)
      console.log 'Updated radio button with id: ' + index + ' ' + id
    return
```

Javascript version of the code above:

```
$(function() {
  return $('.ids-updated-by-js').each(function(index) {
    $(this).find('span').each(function() {
      var id, span;
      span = $(this);
      id = span.find('input').attr('id');
      span.find('input').attr('id', id + index);
      span.find('label').attr('for', id + index);
      return console.log('Updated radio button with id: ' + index + ' ' + id);
    });
  });
});
```

This is not ideal, but it does create the desired effect (as long as the project doesn't have to support `noscript` users).